# The usage of randomstate in Numpy related to seed

Tags: python, numpy, random, deep-learning

I'm working on deep learning lately. During the studying several python scripts, I found this line.

```
numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)
```

I believe this RandomState generates random numbers for bias and weights for
machine learning.

But I have no idea when it comes to that '123' numbers which called 'seed'.

I would like to know what exactly seed does.

Can I just write any number I like? totally it's up to me?

One more, is there a way that I can print the random numbers that were generated
by RandomState?

Comment: Yes, you can use any seed you want. it is just so that the pseudo random produced by the generator are the same from one run to another, to get reproducible results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So the number I write as a 'seed' doesn't do anything.....I can write 234,54354,1234234,2223 any number and it doesn't mean anything right? for example, seed=123 means generate 123 random numbers or something.

Comment: You can pick any value you like, it is not even related to the number of numbers you'll want to generate. it's just a "starting point" to ensure next time you run the program, the same numbers are outputted in this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seed means that the random number generator starts in the same place every time round, which means the outcome is fully deterministic (i.e. not random) from the starting state.

By not using a seed, NumPy will generate a random number (I think) that fills the `seed` which then means the outcome of the deep learning is non-deterministic. In a deep learning example, the results should be *very close*, but will never be identical.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. you mean if I specify the seed as '123' then the random numbers generated as I run the script will be the same every time? and this is why you said 'deterministic'? If I don't specify the seed then every time I run the script it(RandomState) will give different random numbers right?

Comment: That is, to my understanding, correct. Setting the seed means that the random numbers you generate will be the same every time. To simplify imagine your RNG produced:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. By specifying `seed=2`, you specify that the RNG starts from the letter `b` every time. If you let it initialise randomly, it could take any value as the starting point. This means that the outcome of your RNG is always deterministic, therefore reproducable.